# What is this format called (nested shortcodes)?

Tags: shortcode, wp-editor

When using plugins and commercial themes in WordPress, it's not uncommon to meet code like this:

```
[one_half]
    [service_box]
        <h1>Title:</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>blah...</li>
            <li>blah...</li>
            <li>blah...</li>
        </ul>
    [/service_box]
[/one_half]
[one_half_last]
     Something more irrelevant here
[/one_half_last]
```

Does this thing have a name in the WordPress jargon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the phrase

> Nested Shortcodes

to describe it.

You can find [many questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=Nested%20Shortcodes) using that phrase here on WPSE.

The Codex also uses it, for example here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes

Since the shortcodes in your example are related to the layout, we could perhaps call it:

> Nested Layout Shortcodes

to be more specific.

If you have another phrase in mind, or a better suggestion, please share it with us.